# Return ID or Category with the maximum price

Tags: python

I have a csv file with information like 'ID', 'Category', 'Unit Price' and 'Qty' in it.

```
ID Category  Unit_Price  Qty
1    Apple       5        4
2    Grape       8        6
3    Apple       5        2
4   Orange       6        7
5     Pear       4        4
```

What I need is (1) return 'ID' with the maximum price (Unit_Price * Qty) without using pandas or numpy; (2) return 'Category' with the maximum price.

I try to do both by using pandas like

```
# (1) return ID with the maximum price
myindex = (df['Unit_Price']*df['Qty']).idxmax(axis=1)
df['ID'][myindex]

# (2) return Category the with maximum price
df2 = df.reset_index().groupby(['Category'])
df2.sum().sort_values(by='Amount',ascending=False)[:1].index
```

Any pointer or hints? Are there any other more efficient approach?

Comment: Any specific reason you want to do this without pandas?

Comment: it is the easiest using `pandas` or `numpy`. Using pure Python you would have to use `for` loop, rember first value and index and compare with values in other rows to find bigger value. Or you would have to use `for` loop to create list with pairs/tuples `(value, index)` and then you can use `max(list)`

Comment: If you expected not using pandas, why tag pandas ?

Comment: I may fail to express clearly, just looking forward some more efficient solutions no matter using pandas or not, better both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop or list comprehension to create list with tuples `(Unit_Price*Qty, ID, Category)` and then you can use `max()`

`Unit_Price*Qty` has to be first in tuple to get max of this value.

```
data = '''1    Apple       5        4
2    Grape       8        6
3    Apple       5        2
4   Orange       6        7
5     Pear       4        4'''

data = [[item for item in row.split(' ') if item] for row in data.split('\n') ]

# ---------

val, idx, cat = max((int(row[2])*int(row[3]), row[0], row[1]) for row in data)

print(idx, cat, val)
```

Result:

```
2 Grape 48
```

But it gets only one element. If there are more items with the same max value then it will not be useful. You would need dictionary to remember all values using price as key.

I create data with two elements with max price - index 2 and 6

```
data = '''1    Apple       5        4
2    Grape       8        6
3    Apple       5        2
4   Orange       6        7
5     Pear       4        4
6    Grape       8        6'''

data = [[item for item in row.split(' ') if item] for row in data.split('\n') ]

# ---------

results = dict()

for row in data:
    val = int(row[2])*int(row[3])
    idx = row[0]
    cat = row[1]
    if val not in results:
        results[val] = []
    results[val].append( (idx, cat) )

max_val = max(results.keys())

print(max_val, results[max_val])
```

Result:

```
48 [('2', 'Grape'), ('6', 'Grape')]
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with `pandas` need only two lines

```
data = '''1    Apple       5        4
2    Grape       8        6
3    Apple       5        2
4   Orange       6        7
5     Pear       4        4
6    Grape       8        6'''

data = [[item for item in row.split(' ') if item] for row in data.split('\n') ]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Category', 'Unit_Price', 'Qty'])
df['Unit_Price'] = df['Unit_Price'].map(int)
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].map(int)

# ---------

df['price'] = df['Unit_Price']*df['Qty']
print( df[ df['price'].max() == df['price'] ][['ID', 'Category']] )
```

Result:

```
  ID Category
1  2    Grape
5  6    Grape
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data = []
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip().split())

result = sorted(data[1:], key=lambda x: float(x[2])*int(x[3]))[-1]
_id, category, price, qty = result

print(f'id: {_id}, category: {category}, unit price: {price}, qty: {qty}, total price: {float(price)*int(qty)}')
```

output:

```
id: 2, category: Grape, unit price: 8, qty: 6, total price: 48.0
```